# Перемещение строки из одной таблицы в другую JS

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста решить задачку. Есть таблица на странице index.html. При нажатии на кнопку Delete в конкретной строке  - эта строка должна удалиться из таблицы и попасть в таблицу на страницу deleted.html.
Нужно обойтись чистым JS на стороне браузера. Отображать данные в таблицах на другом ПК или в другом браузере задача не стоит.
По моему мнению, можно попробовать активную строку таблицы поместить в localstorage, а потом ее оттуда забирать в другую таблицу, это было бы хорошим вариантом для меня. Как реализовать - хз.
Или перекраивать логику и сделать переключение страниц в виде вкладок через параметр display. Но с этим тоже надо разбираться, я же новичок.
P.S. если вам не сложно, постарайтесь рассказать немного поподробнее, чтобы не заниматься тупо копипастой. Спасибо!

index.html и функция на кнопке **Add**:

```js
        function insertRow(id) {
            var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
            var row;
            row = document.createElement("tr");
            row.setAttribute("id", "tr_id")
            var cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
            var td1 = document.createElement("td");
            td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));
            var td2 = document.createElement("td");
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input")
            checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            checkbox.setAttribute("id", "checkbox_id");
            td2.appendChild(checkbox);
            var td3 = document.createElement("td");
            td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));
            var td4 = document.createElement("td");
            td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));
            var td5 = document.createElement("td");
            td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));
            var td6 = document.createElement("td");
            var editButton = document.createElement("input")
            editButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
            editButton.setAttribute("value", "Edit");
            td6.appendChild(editButton);
            var deleteButton = document.createElement("input")
            deleteButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
            deleteButton.setAttribute("value", "Delete");
            td6.appendChild(deleteButton);
            td6.setAttribute("colspan", "2")
            row.appendChild(td1);
            row.appendChild(td2);
            row.appendChild(td3);
            row.appendChild(td4);
            row.appendChild(td5);
            row.appendChild(td6);
            
            tbody.appendChild(row);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Cart</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
            <li><a href="done.html">Done</a></li>
            <li><a href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
        <hr class="hr">
        <input type="text" id="add_id" placeholder="Add items ti you Shopping List">
        <input type="text" id="quant_id" placeholder="Quant.">
        <input type="text" id="price_id" placeholder="Price">
        <button type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable');return false;">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="table">
        <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>#</td>
                    <td>Done</td>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Price $</td>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" width="100">Action</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="js/insertRow.js"></script>
</html>
```

deleted.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Cart</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
            <li><a href="done.html">Done</a></li>
            <li><a href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 class="h1">Deleted Items</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="table">
        <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr onclick="alert(this.rowIndex)">
                    <td>#</td>
                    <td>Done</td>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Price $</td>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" width="100">Action</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: хороший вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

Основная трудность - хранить данные. Если у вас две разные страницы html, нужно как-то переносить между ними данные. Варианты:

1. В параметрах GET (в адресной строке браузера) - плохо, есть ограничение на размер, при больших размерах таблицы будет огромная ссылка. Но в целом выполнимо
2. Через серверную сторону (БД, сессия сервера или еще как-то) - нельзя, нужно использовать чистый JS на стороне браузера, судя по формулировке вопроса
3. Через куки браузера - странно, данные будут работать только в конкретном браузере. При открытии страниц в другом браузере или на другом ПК - данные не будут сохранены, потому что хранятся в браузере

Получается, что имея только чистый JS (а он работает на стороне браузера), нельзя перенести данные от одной страницы к другой. Потому что при открытии другой страницы весь JS на этой странице умирает. А JS для новой страницы - рождается. Между ними нужен "мост" - обычно это серверная часть как раз, backend

Если бы у вас была серверная часть хотя бы в каком-то виде, которой можно было бы сказать - "создай строку / дай строку / обнови строку / удали строку" (CRUD - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD), то задача решалась бы элементарно. Но на чистом JS на стороне браузера это скорее головоломка, чем задача.

Смиритесь с этим или дополните вопрос подробностями или деталями.

Comment: а что если уйти от многостраничности и использовать display для отображения таблиц?
Однако, отображать данные в таблицах на другом ПК или в другом браузере задача не стоит. Если бы активную строку таблицы можно было поместить в localstorage, а потом ее оттуда забирать в другую таблицу, это было бы хорошим вариантом для меня.

Comment: Да, тогда можно. Вы можете например сделать два таба / две колонки - вот таблица, вот удаленные строки. И перетаскивать между этими двумя табами строки таблицы. Но все изменения пропадут, если вы обновите страницу.

Comment: Если вы сделаете два примитива - хранилище для таблицы + что-то, прорисовывающее таблицу в контейнер, то задача решится элементарно.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Для начала я попробую поместить строку таблицы в хранилище. Скорее всего всю строку как один объект получить не получится (возможно я ошибаюсь), поэтому я постараюсь сделать поячеечно.

Comment: Посмотрите на http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/ . Вы для определенной таблицы можете выбрать все строки `$("#table tr").map(function(i,tr){...});`, а потом для каждой строки выбрать ее ячейки внутри обработчика строк - `$(tr).find("td").map(function(i,td){...});`. Если перенести данные в глобальную переменную по строкам (самое простое - в массив из массивов), то у вас будет хранилище

Comment: Ну а для отрисовки этого хранилища достаточно просто грамотно пройтись двумя циклами - по строкам и по ячейкам - и нарисовать текст HTML, который можно вставить в страницу простым `$("#table").html(super_text_here);`. Удачи!